# EventListeners Not getting called with Instance created through Reflection

Tags: c#, events, system.reflection

Apologies had a typo...have edited...

I have a weird issue I am not sure about.

In one piece of code I have a class which is called as a singleton which has an event other classes can listen to, pretty straightforward by doing something like

```
Client.Instance.MyEvent += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(myHandler);
```

So if I have a generic class:

```
Class MyTest {
   public MyTest() {
       System.Console.WriteLine("In Constructor Registering Events");
       Client.Instance.MyEvent += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(myHandler);
   }
   private void myHandler(object sender, EventArgs arg) {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Got event!");
   }
}
```

Now if i create the class like:

```
MyTest mC = new MyTest ();
Client.Instance.FireEvent();
```

I get the expected "In Constructor Registering Events" and "Got Event"

However if i create the class through Reflection, I do not.

```
Type mType = typeof(MyTest);
object mT = Activator.CreateInstance(mType);
Client.Instance.FireEvent();
```

All i get is "In Constructor Registering Events"  but i DO NOT get the event fired message.  whats going on here? Am i doing something incorrectly in my reflection calls?

Thanks -

Comment: Did you mean `object mC = Activator.CreateInstance(mType);` ?

Comment: I did, i have edited the original post.  A few typos.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your claim and, with the proper type, it works the same whether the object is created using `new` or via reflection.

The following [Working Demo can be tested here](http://rextester.com/live/BMH36978)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {                        
        Client.Instance.MyEvent += delegate { Console.WriteLine("MY EVENT handled from Main"); };

        MyTest mt = new MyTest();

        Type mType = typeof(MyTest);
        object reflectedMT = Activator.CreateInstance(mType);

        Client.Instance.FireEvent();
    }
}

public class Client {
    private Client() {}
    private static Client _inst = new Client();
    public static Client Instance { get { return _inst; } }
    public void FireEvent() { if(MyEvent != null) MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty); }
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
}

public class MyTest {
   public MyTest() {
      System.Console.WriteLine("In Constructor Registering Events");
      Client.Instance.MyEvent += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(myHandler);
   }
   private void myHandler(object sender, EventArgs arg) {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Got event!");
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean exactly but you can't invoke methods on the UI from a non-UI thread. If that's what happening you will have to use the Invoke() method of one of your Controls to call your code on the UI thread instead of the other non-UI thread.

Comment: Ah it was my fault, in the client code where "FireEvent" is called, it was actually in a while loop (after i get data off a socket) i was using a delegate to fire the event, and the delegate was initalized outside of the loop, so once it got into the while loop, effectivly even though event += was called it wasnt being registered.  all is well now.  thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: glad to hear you solved your problem.. you might show your appreciation by voting on the answer if you thought it helped ;)